# Pull out genes/observations from cutree_rows groups in pheatmap

Tags: r, heatmap, hierarchical-clustering, pheatmap, rna-seq

How can you pull out the genes/observations from the row groups generated from `cutree_rows = 3` in `pheatmap`? would be `obj$tree_row$...`?

```
obj <- pheatmap(mat, annotation_col = anno, fontsize_row = 10, show_colnames = F, show_rownames = F, cutree_cols = 3, cluster_cols = FALSE, color = col, scale = 'row',cutree_rows = 3)
```

I have seen you can find the gene list if you apply k means by running `obj$kmeans$cluster` like in here [is there a way to preserve the clustering in a heatmap but reduce the number of observations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43805277/is-there-a-way-to-preserve-the-clustering-in-a-heatmap-but-reduce-the-number-of/43807553#43807553)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do cutree on it again, so for example data is such:

```
set.seed(2020)
mat = matrix(rnorm(200),20,10)
rownames(mat) = paste0("g",1:20)
obj = pheatmap(mat,cluster_cols = FALSE, scale = 'row',cutree_rows = 3)
```

[image]

Do cutree :

```
cl = cutree(obj$tree_row,3)

ann = data.frame(cl)
rownames(ann) = rownames(mat)

ann
    cl
g1   1
g2   2
g3   1
g4   2
g5   3
g6   1
g7   2
g8   1
g9   1
g10  2
g11  3
g12  2
g13  2
g14  1
g15  2
g16  2
g17  1
g18  3
g19  3
g20  2
```

We plot this again to see it's correct,

```
pheatmap(mat,cluster_cols = FALSE, scale = 'row',cutree_rows = 3,annotation_row=ann)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I wanted, thanks @StupidWolf :)